# Implement SQL/CASE Statement in Pyspark where a column 'contains' a list of string or a column 'like' a list of string

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, case

I am trying to implement a SQL/Case statement type logic in Pyspark. I know there's spark.sql() to run sql code within spark
or df.withColumn with expr() but my situation is bit different in that there's a part of the logic that I can't
replicate in SQL.

```
CASE WHEN trim(col1)='000' then '0'
WHEN trim(col1) in ('061', '062', '063', '064', '081', '082', '083', '084','110','112','113','114','115','116')  then 'U'
WHEN ( col1 like '%A%'  | col1 like '%A%' | col1 like '%B%' | col1 like '%C%' | col1 like '%C%' | col1 like '%D%' ... ... )
else 'Y' end as col2
```

My issue is with line 3 . It needs to cover A-Z all 26 alphabates.

```
WHEN ( col1 like '%A%'  | col1 like '%A%' | col1 like '%B%' | col1 like '%C%' | col1 like '%C%' | col1 like '%D%' ... ...
```

'Contains' could have worked - but It works for only single string value. I dont know if there's a way
to pass a list of elements for contains - like " col1 contains ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' ... ...) "

So far what I have is something like following .

```
list_a = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','Z']

from functools import reduce
newdf1 = df.where(reduce(lambda a, b: a|b, (df['col1'].like('%'+pat+"%") for pat in list_a)))

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
newdf1 = newdf1.withColumn("col2", lit('C'))
```

So the output looks like this :

```
+---------+----------+--
col1    |  col2        |
+---------+----------+--
      A00|            C|                
      A00|            C|                
      B00|            C|                
      G00|            C| 
      K00|            C|                
      M00|            C|
```

But this is not a good solution as it is filtering the dataframe as opposed to keeping the dataframe newdf1 intact. Any suggestions how I can
improve this ?

Comment: You could replace those 25x "or" for each letter with a regex match [A-Z] in most sql. I'm not familiar with spark, but from a quick google it looks like you have regex support included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rlike`(other): SQL RLIKE expression (LIKE with Regex). Returns a boolean Column based on a regex match.   Parameters:  other – an extended regex expression

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
('A00',),
('B00',),
('C00',),
('K00',),
('M00',),
('000',),
],["col1"])

df.withColumn('col2', when( col('col1').rlike("[a-zA-Z]"), regexp_extract(col('col1'), "[a-zA-Z]", 0) ).otherwise(lit(None))).show(10)

# +----+----+
# |col1|col2|
# +----+----+
# | A00|   A|
# | B00|   B|
# | C00|   C|
# | K00|   K|
# | M00|   M|
# | 000|null|
# +----+----+
```